# Alienware 17R3 + Ubuntu 17.10: headphones does not work properly

Tags: sound, headphones, 17.10, alienware

When I insert headphones I see it in Settings->Sound->Output instead of speakers but sound plays through internal speakers anyway.

The only way is to execute

```
amixer -c 0 sset "HP/Speaker" on
```

to switch headphones on and

```
amixer -c 0 sset "HP/Speaker" off
```

to switch it off back to speakers

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem I had a year ago was fixed automaticly by "PulseAudio Volume Control". I don't remember which hardware that laptop had, but I see the same symptoms.

Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

then just

```
$ pavucontrol
```

Comment: Unfortunately pavucontrol unable to activate headphones at all. I played with it about 30 min, no success. The more, it does not matter amixer or pavucontrol. I ask if someone knows how to config 17.10 on Alienware to automatically select proper output device.